# Is it true that for a matrix $A$ with non-zero entries, $\det{A}=0 \iff$ its cofactors are $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

We know that through cofactor expansion, the determinant of an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ may be written as a linear combination of the determinants of it's cofactors. Let $A_{i,j}\neq 0$ denote the $i,j$'th entry of $A$ and $M_{i,j}$ the determinant of $A$ with its $i$'th row and $j$'th column removed. Then the cofactor expansion is

$$\det(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+j}A_{i,j}M_{i,j}.$$

Right away we can see that if the minors are $0$, the $\det(A)=0$. Is it true in the opposite direction? If not, are there nice conditions for this?

One would expect not, since in the case $n=2$ the minors are simply constants and we know of non-zero $2 \times 2$ matrices with $0$ determinant. One angle might be to apply the cofactor expansion to each of the minors such that $\det(A)$ is written as a weight sum of $2\times 2$ matrices, which makes you hopeful that it would give the condition that any $2\times 2$ submatrix have non-zero determinant but even then you still have the possibility of terms cancelling, so this approach would not work.

Comment: You've already shown it's not true in the opposite direction by examining $n=2$

Comment: Yeah, this isn't true in reverse. There are lots of ways to get zero in that sum.

Comment: What does "nice conditions" mean? Do you mean, some global condition on $A$ that will guarantee that each minor is non-invertible?

Comment: Any matrix $A$ of rank $n-1$ will have some nonzero minor of order $n-1$, but $\det(A)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

For a $3 \times 3$ example you might consider

$$ \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 4 & 2 
\\
 1 & 3 & 1 
\\
 1 & 1 & -1 
\end{array}\right]
$$

where the determinant is $0$, but all entries and cofactors are nonzero.